# Having trouble with case loop

Tags: c, case

please. I want a display for options from 'A' to 'H', however the "default invalid option" kept appearing. How do i prevent the "default invalid option from apprearing. Thanks so much if you could give me a hand.

```
void disp3Ave (void)
{
    int day, total;
    char j;
    extern float PSI23ave[];
    extern float PSI24ave[];
    extern float PSI25ave[];
    float average;
    total=0;
    printf("Day 23 or 24?\n");
    scanf("%\d", &day);

    if(day == 23)
    {
        printf("A: 0300.\n");
        printf("B: 0600.\n");
        printf("C: 0900.\n");
        printf("D: 1200.\n");
        printf("E: 1500.\n");
        printf("F: 1800.\n");
        printf("G: 2100.\n");
        printf("H: 0000.\n");
        scanf("%c", &j);

        switch (j)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A': total= PSI23ave[3] + PSI23ave[4] + PSI23ave[5];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[6] + PSI23ave[7] + PSI23ave[8];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[9] + PSI23ave[10] + PSI23ave[11];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[12] + PSI23ave[13] + PSI23ave[14];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[15] + PSI23ave[16] + PSI23ave[17];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[18] + PSI23ave[19] + PSI23ave[20];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'g':
            case 'G': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI23ave[21] + PSI23ave[22] + PSI23ave[23];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;
            case 'h':
            case 'H': for (j=0;j<24;j++) total= PSI24ave[0] + PSI24ave[1] + PSI24ave[2];
                  average = total/3;
                  printf("3-hr average = %.1f\n", average);
                  break;

            default: printf("Invalid option.\n");
                 break;

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! cheers!

Comment: Changed the tag to C from C++.

Comment: Please, compile with all warnings and debug info (i.e. `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) Improve the code till you get no warnings. Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), the memory leak detector (e.g. [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ...)

Comment: `"%\d"`? I'm not sure why this seems to work..  should just be `"%d"`

Comment: BTW, I am not sure about `scanf("%\d", &day);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that when you enter the value for the int variable `day`, the character `'\n'` remains in the input buffer.
This gets stored in your variable `j` and hence you get Invalid option.

Edit:
You can try `scanf("\n%c", &j);`

Comment: you may want to demonstrate how to address the issue with `fgetc` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As user1990169 concluded, the issue is that the buffer reads the integer from stdin, but the newline character remains in the input buffer.  This can be addressed in a number of ways, but the simplest is to add a call to `getchar()` which will read one character from the input stream.

```
scanf("%d", &day); // remove the \ before d
getchar();
```

---

here's a small program to demonstrate:

```
int main(void) {
  int day = -1;
  char c = 'x';
  scanf("%d", &day);
  getchar(); // this line
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("read: %d %c\n", day, c);
}
```

if you remove the call to `getchar()` you'll see that there is no wait before reading the character, it will just immediately read a newline into the `c` variable.

There are more advanced options to deal with input separated by an unknown number of spaces using `isspace` and `ungetc`, but for your simple program, this should suffice.

Additionally, instead of having a case for the uppercase and lowercase, you can convert the character and only have one case label for each:

```
j = toupper(j); // #include <ctype.h>
```